# limit of 2-dimensional function

Tags: calculus, limits

Am I right with these limits?
$$
\lim_{r \uparrow 1}
   \left(r^{3/4}-r^{-3/4}\right) \sin\left(\frac{3}{4}\phi\right)=0
$$
for $r \in (0,1)$ and $\phi \in (0,\frac{4}{3}\pi)$, as the function is continuous at 1  and you can  plug in the point 1 to get the limit.

$$
\lim_{\phi \uparrow \frac{4}{3}\pi}
    \left(r^{3/4}-r^{-3/4}\right) \sin\left(\frac{3}{4}\phi\right)
= \lim_{\phi \downarrow 0}
    \left(r^{3/4}-r^{-3/4}\right) \sin\left(\frac{3}{4}\phi\right)
= 0
$$
for  $r \in (0,1)$ and $\phi \in (0,\frac{4}{3}\pi)$, as the function is also continuous at $0$ and $\frac{4}{3}\pi$ and you can plug these two points in the functions which is zero because of $sin(0)=0$

Comment: Looks fine to me. +1 . Just detail a little more carefully what do you *really* mean when you say "the function's continuous at $\;1\;$..." This is a two variables functions, so $\;1\;$ what?

Comment: You understand, I hope, that the "sin" part is irrelevant to this?  Since the limit is taken as r goes to 1, the limit given will be 0 if and only if [tex]\lim_{r\to 1) r^{1/4}- r^{-3/4}[/tex] and that is just [tex]1^{1/4}- 1^{-3/4}= 1- 1= 0[/tex].

Comment: @user247327 Remember to write dollar sign $ instead of [tex]

Comment: Yes i understand. It is continuous because, it has no break at the point 1. and because of composition of continuous functions this is continuous.

Comment: $|\;(r^{3/4}-r^{-3/4}) \sin (3 \phi /4)\;|\leq |r^{3/4}-r^{-3/4}|.$